# Introductory books on Sieve methods

Tags: number-theory

I want to start learning sieve methods, but the books I have come across is quite advanced, anyone know of easier books?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your background?

Comment: I have finished my undergraduate degree in mathematics. I have done some number theory and real/complex analysis. But I am having a tough time with the analysis part.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *An Introduction to Sieve Methods and Their Applications* by Cojocaru and Murty. It claims to be suitable for senior undergraduates.

Comment: This book has about 200 pages. Which book would you recommend after reading this?

Comment: @user114790 I'm no expert, so I don't know.